# Can not call a function outside the class without self but self throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class that detects events within a folder, this works. However when I try to run a function to deal with the data i get the error: `on_any_event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`. I need to be able to call the file mover class from that function as the event.src_path is there.

Heres my Handler class:

```
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, choice):
        self.choice=choice

    def fileMover(self, src_path):
        choice=self.choice
        print("choice: "+choice)





    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print("Received created event - %s" % event.src_path)
            self.fileMover(event.src_path)


        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            print("Received modified event - %s" % event.src_path)
```

Comment: A staticmethod can't access self. If it is needed in the method, the method can't be static.

Comment: this may help https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: I took away the static method but now I am getting the error:  name 'event' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was that I needed to change 
`@staticmethod` ---->  `@classmethod`